# Show second form on button click in delphi android

Tags: android, delphi

Raise error when I touch button and debugger call form.show.

> Project AVA.apk raised exception class EJNIException with message 'android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'.

Unit2:

```
var  
   frmSettings: TfrmSettings;
```

Unit1 Button onClick event:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmSettings:=TfrmSettings.Create(Application);
  frmSettings.Show;
end;
```

Comment: There's not enough here to recreate your problem. Can you please provide us an MCVE?

Comment: @JerryDodge Please read my code carefully ^^^.

Comment: I did read your code very carefully, and I see two lines of code that I use all the time which should work. What's in this form? Does this other form call something else? Are you utilizing device views? Are you able to start a new project with nothing in it and reproduce the problem?

Comment: Just for a trial, pass `nil` instead of `Application`. Theoretically, that should work the way you have it, but it's worth a try. That's the only advise based on what I'm able to see.

Comment: Please confirm that you get the error message with following setup: two forms: 1) TfrmMain with a TButton and OnClick event as you show. 2) TfrmSettings, empty form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code you provided itself is not cause of error. However, code that executes during creation and/or showing your form might.

You seem to be using/calling native Android API's that need to run in context of Android UI thread. Since Delphi main thread and Android UI thread are different threads you are triggering error.

To avoid it use:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSettingsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CallInUiThread(procedure
    begin
      frmSettings:=TfrmSettings.Create(Application);
      frmSettings.Show;  
    end);  
end;
```